# Interface Inheritence & Overloads

Tags: c#, oop, interface, overloading

I am dealing with an interface as follows:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    ...many auto-props, 
    void SetValues(ISomething thing) 
}
```

Now, I don't own this interface, but I'd like to extend it with a couple more properties:

```
public interface ISomethingMoreSpecific : ISomething
{ 
    ...existing + my props, 
    void SetValues(ISomething thing)
}
```

In the class the implements `ISomethingMoreSpecific` I've implemented an overload that takes the derived interface and handles both my props and the base interface properties.

```
public void SetValues(ISomethingMoreSpecific specificThing) 
{
    ...set my props and base props
}
```

The calling code does the following:

```
myThing.SetValues((ISomethingMoreSpecific)otherThing);
```

With or without the cast, the method will not dispatch to my overload even though `otherThing` and `myThing` are concrete types implementing `ISomethingMoreSpecific`. I am guessing I'm overlooking something simple, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include

```
void SetValues(ISomethingMoreSpecific specificThing);
```

into ISomethingMoreSpecific.

Answer (score 0):

You have `void SetValues(ISomething thing)` again in `ISomethingMoreSpecific`. Do you intend to hide that, then use the `new` keyword. If you do not want to hide that you need to change `void SetValues(ISomething thing)` to `void SetValues(ISomethingMoreSpecific)` in `ISomethingMoreSpecific`. Below is the code when you intend to hide and it does work with casting. Even if you don't hide it, i.e. don't use the `new` keyword. it works.

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyThing a = new MyThing();
        MyThing b = new MyThing();
        a.SetValues(b);//calls more specific
        a.SetValues((ISomething)b);//calls just the thing
    }   
}


public class MyThing : ISomethingMoreSpecific
{
    public void SetValues(ISomethingMoreSpecific specificThing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("more specific");
    }

    public void SetValues(ISomething thing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("just the thing");
    }
}

public interface ISomethingMoreSpecific : ISomething
{ 
    //...existing + my props, 
    new void SetValues(ISomething thing);
}

public interface ISomething
{
    //...many auto-props, 
    void SetValues(ISomething thing) ;
}
```